# upload photo and publish story using FBConnect

Tags: iphone, image, facebook, upload, fbconnect

In my iphone app,I want to let the user upload an image to his facebook photo Album and publish a story at the same time.The story's media field contains the uploaded image's url.I successly uploaded the photo and got the result's "link" and "src_small" property.But when I use FBStreamDialog to publish the story,I got:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sinaimg.cn](http://ss10.sinaimg.cn/orignal/5d84b24ag89d4c79cbcb9&690))</sub>

At last,I find this:[http://developers.facebook.com/live_status#msg_625](https://developers.facebook.com/status/dashboard/#msg_625),it says:

```
We no longer allow stream stories to contain images that are hosted on the fbcdn.net domain. The images associated with these URLs aren't always optimized for stream stories and occasionally resulted in errors, leading to a poor user experience. Make sure your stream attachments don't reference images with this domain. You should host the images locally.
```

It seems that I can't finish my job,What's your solution? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can't use that picture or the picture from facebook itself

you can upload the picture on other servers or upload it to online photo sharing like picasa

Answer (score 0):

I got this functionality to work with ShareKit - it's really good:
http://www.getsharekit.com/

It's also open source, so you can see how they do it inside...

Good luck!

Comment: Hm, perhaps I did something wrong, but images do appear in the photoalbum, but there is no story posted.